# Combining data from 2 rows into 1

Tags: row, pivot

I have an extremely complex query. I want the 2 row data combine in to 1 row.

It gives me the following Output

```
         PNAME    RN         LVN        HA         MSW       SC
           AA     AG-1W      SS-1M     LO-2W      PA-1W      SK-1M
           AA     JL-1W      TD -1M     NULL      NULL       NULL
```

IS there any way I could have the results in 1 Row or Combine the 2 Rows in to 1. Like As Follows.

```
            PNAME      RN         LVN        HA        MSW         SC
             AA       AG-1W      SS-1M     LO-2W      PA-1W      SK-1M
                      JL-1W      TD -1M     NULL       NULL       NULL
```

Comment: Forogot to ask for, your table schema definition. Can you please share it?

Comment: Is there any generic method to do it

Comment: Generic method to do what? If you are referring to table schema definition, can you put it like the following at least?
(mine is just an example). If you can put yours that's helpful.

tblpatient (`id` int, `name` varchar(9),`SOC` varchar(5), `EOC` varchar(9), `HospiceID` int)


tblstaff (`id` int, `name` varchar(20), `discipline` varchar(9))

tblassignment
 (`id` int, `pid` int, `sid` int,`assignment` varchar(9))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve, but you can implement usage of `row_number()` to prevent the `pname` from showing in additional rows:

```
select case when rownum = 1 then pname else '' end pname, 
    [RN], [LVN], [HA], [MSW], [SC]
from
(
    select pname, disc, value,
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by disc order by disc) rownum
    from temp
) src
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for disc in ([RN], [LVN], [HA], [MSW], [SC])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fcdc/1)

results:

```
| PNAME |    RN |   LVN |     HA |    MSW |     SC |
----------------------------------------------------
|    AA | AG-1W | SS-1M |  LO-2W |  PA-1W |  SK-1M |
|       | JL-1W | TD-1M | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

This uses to the value of the `row_number()` to decide if the `pname` should be displayed.  It will only show the value when the `rownum=1`, otherwise it will be blank.

If you want the data in a single row, you can use something similar to the following:

```
;with cte as
(
  select pname, disc, value,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by disc order by disc) rownum
  from temp
),
piv as 
(
  select * 
  from cte
  pivot
  (
    max(value)
    for disc in ([RN], [LVN], [HA], [MSW], [SC])
  ) piv
)
select pname,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + [RN]  
              from piv p2
              where p1.pname = p2.pname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') RN,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + [LVN]  
              from piv p2
              where p1.pname = p2.pname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') LVN,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + [HA]  
              from piv p2
              where p1.pname = p2.pname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') HA,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + [MSW]  
              from piv p2
              where p1.pname = p2.pname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') MSW,   
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ', ' + [SC]  
              from piv p2
              where p1.pname = p2.pname
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') SC   
from piv p1
group by pname
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8fcdc/16)

The result is:

```
| PNAME |            RN |           LVN |     HA |    MSW |     SC |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|    AA |  AG-1W, JL-1W |  SS-1M, TD-1M |  LO-2W |  PA-1W |  SK-1M |
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. Probably I wasn't clear about what I want in the previous post. Instead of displaying the results in a different row and not having the PNAME is it possible to display them in a way that only 1 row only. The rows are merged somehow

Comment: @user1764540 see my edit which will concatenate the values into a single row but not with a line break, it uses a comma between the values